# Formatting Buttons in jQuery for Forums

Tags: javascript, jquery, markdown

I want to do something as simple as emulate the buttons as can be seen here—albeit in jQuery and Django.

I have scoured the net and found nothing, which surprises me, but I figure it is because I am not using the right terminology.

Right now, I want to include inline tags like `strong`, `em`, and `code` and more tricky things like links and images (using Markdown and HTML syntax).

I figure that there are two to three different states for jQuery to act on:

1. Some text has been selected; the text is decorated.
2. Nothing has been selected; jQuery prompts the user to enter the text to be decorated.
3. The script can discern between highlighted text and a highlighted URL to decide for when it needs to produce a valid link.

I have already done some jQuery stuff, so the basics of it should be manageable (any potential JS regex aside); I just have no idea to which extent jQuery supports this.

Comment: What buttons? Here on Stackoverflow? Which page?

Comment: @DavidThomas: That page, *waaaaay* over yonder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize a Rich Text editor to perform your tasks. This blog post lists some of them -

http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors

I have used TinyMCE and it is also very good. Apart from that I have used EphoxEdit Live( http://editlive.com/what-new ) and that is pretty good(though not a jQuery plugin) for heavy usage like content editing.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a WYSIWYG(What You See Is What You Get) editor.

[tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/) comes to mind.

or you can search the [jQuery Plugins Page](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/wysiwyg)

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good place to start: [jQuery WYSIWYG Plugin](https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg)